# Can someone explain why this is true? $\int f(x) g'(x)\,dx = \int f(x)\,dg$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm a software engineer (have been for 20+ years) and have over the past few years taken quite an interest in math. I would appreciate it if anyone is able to help me out with my question.

I understand the following:

$$\int g’(x)\,dx = \int dg$$

This makes sense to me.

$$\int g’(x)\,dx = g(x)+c$$
$$\int dg = g(x) + c$$

That being the case, $\displaystyle \int g'(x)\,dx = \int dg$.

As far as I know, this is also true:

$$\int f(x)g’(x)\,dx = \int f(x)\,dg$$

What I don't completely understand is why you can put $f(x)$ in each of these integrals and they continue to be equal. I mean, I understand that if $\int g’(x)\,dx = \int dg$, then I should be able to swap $g’(x)\,dx$ for $dg$ (or vice versa), but I'm trying to visualize how $f(x)$ doesn't somehow throw this off.

Just reading it, I am looking for the integral of $f(x)$ multiplied by $g’(x)$ with respect to $x$ and the integral of $f(x)$ with respect to $g$.

Can someone explain the logic of this to me and/or point me to an applicable proof? I've Googled around to see if I can find a good explanation, but I must not be describing my question in the search query well enough (hopefully I am doing an OK job describing it here).

Comment: It seems that $\exp A$ is irrelevant here and only the relation ${\rm d}g = g'(x)\,{\rm d}x$ plays a role. So $\int \exp A\,{\rm d}g = \int \exp A\,g'\,{\rm d}x$. (Surely there are a few abuses of notation such as omitting points of application in the functions, but I'm not going to nitpick on this here)

Comment: You might find reading up on the Riemann-Stieljes integral to be fruitful -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: What does $A$ stand for? a number? a matrix of constants? a matrix of functions of $x$?

Comment: I should have been more clear on what I intended (expA) to mean. I just meant that to convey some arbitrary expression such as x^2, 27x, or similar.

For example:

∫ 27x ′=∫ 27x 

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I think you may have answered my question. :)

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Just an FYI that I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: You used expA to mean an arbitrary expression such as $x^2, $27x$ or similar? Remind me never to bother responding to any of your posts again.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Harsh :) I should have made that more clear. Sorry about that. I didn't mean to waste your time there.

Answer (score 1):

What you should read is that, by definition, $dg=g'(x)\,dx$. This relation holds independently of integration.

For example, you can use it in the chain rule,

$$\frac{dg}{dt}=g'(x)\frac{dx}{dt}.$$

[If you want to be picky, $\dfrac{dg(x(t))}{dt}=g'(x(t))\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}$.]

Comment: So, I have been through a proof of the chain rule and that totally makes sense to me. I understand in that case why we can (essentially) cancel dt as in your example.

One thing that is not clear to me is what something like dg (by itself) means independent of integration. I know if we are looking to find the anti-derivative of (just) dg that it is equal to g(x) + c (and that makes sense), but I'm not sure what dg means (again, by itself) outside of the context of integration.

Comment: @MikeTutkowski: I showed you in the context of differentiation. What more do you want ?

Comment: $\int f(x) dg$ is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, and does not require the function $g$ to be differentiable. Under certain conditions is $\int f(x) dg = \int f(x) g'(x) dx$, but that is (as I understand it) a *theorem* and not a simple matter of *defining* $dg$ as $g'(x) dx$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I believe you have clarified this for me. It is not a simple matter of definition, but rather there exists an underlying theorem that explains why this equality exists.

Overall, I am able to perform the necessary steps to transform this into that, but sometimes the sources I am learning from do not always make it clear why this is allowed. I assume when they don't go into such details that it is because doing so would require a long digression. I wish they would just explicitly say this, though, when that is the case. :)

Answer (score -2):

As Yves Daoust writes, this is from the simple fact:

$$\frac{dg}{dt} \cdot dt = /\text{ cancel dt }/=dg$$

This is independent of integration.

Comment: Although I remember that we can perform this cancelation, it brings up another question for me: Why exactly are we allowed to treat dt as cancelable? I guess I am saying the following: I understand here how we can perform this and that transformation, but I'm not always sure why it is permitted.

I have walked through a proof of the chain rule, so I understand in that case why such a cancelation is permitted.

Comment: One thing that is not clear to me (and perhaps this would solve many of my questions) is what something like dg means independent of integration. I know if we are integrating dg that it is equivalent to g(x) + c (and that makes sense), but I'm not sure what dg means outside of the context of integration. Thanks!

Comment: dg means small slice of g. d is like delta letter in greek alphabet often used for small differences.

Comment: $dt$ and $dg$ are not numbers, but symbols used in the Riemann and Riemann-Stieltjes integral. It requires some justification why such a “cancellation” is allowed.

Comment: @MartinR You can construct many useful integrals using just some basic geometry together with symbols like "dx". Typical examples include volume calculation of rotatoids. This is often done already in high-school. No need to make it overly complicated. It is not like we are investigating properties of functional analysis here.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. The question here is about an identity between Riemann and Riemann-Stieltjes integral (and OP made it clear in the comments that he wants to know why this transformation is valid). That are two well-defined concepts, and telling “just treat these as a small differences/slices and cancel” is missing mathematical preciseness in my opinion. This has nothing to to with functional analysis or “making things overly complicated.”

Comment: @MartinR I disagree. The question does not mention whether we should consider Riemann or Lebesgue or other theories of integration and what would be necessary in those theories.

Comment: The question is about $\int f(x)g’(x)\,dx = \int f(x)\,dg$, and the RHS *is* a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: You can define *very* many other kinds of integrals using that notation.